# How to mentor a newbie tester when I lack relevant experience?

Tags: learning, team

I have been working as a developer in software industry for the past 8 years. I have seen many projects and worked as a dev lead which also involves interacting with QA team to get the testing done of the project I am working on and follow the process of providing releases to QA, fixing defects (defect life cycle) etc. But I have never got a chance to see how a tester work in terms of preparing test plans, testing cycles, test cases etc.

Now, I am leading a very small team where there is no separate lead/supervisor for testing team. Since its a small team, there is only one manual tester who happens to be a fresher from college. I have to mentor him, and I really want him to learn and get a good base for himself. The problem is, I myself do not know much about that domain. I do not want him to suffer because of it.

Can you help me know how to mentor in such scenario? How can I help him learn and grow?

Comment: I'd say this question is a better fit for 
Project Management SE.

Comment: Or workplace SE

Comment: @mehta the moderators feel this would be more appropriate in project management or workplace than here.  Let us know which you prefer and we will move it there.

Comment: @JeanneBoyarsky, can you please move it to Project Management Forum please?

Answer (score 1):

First off, mentoring is all about helping someone perform or develop through improving their behaviour, communications, or other changes. Mentoring someone in a field outside your own has some challenges, but these can all be managed. As a mentor it is not your job to teach the specific technical subject.

In your scenario, the things you can help with include:

- supporting him in finding out information (this could include subsidising online learning, or encouraging him to join a local programmers forum, or even SE :-))
- helping find individuals who can help (can you talk to other team leads and see if there is a possible opportunity?)
- help him with the non-technical aspects. It sounds like he won't have a direct support network, so this could be quite stressful - his first job since graduation - part of your role is to help him adjust.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to take some training courses in order to improve your skills, so that you'll become more experienced and confident in your testing knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking you as a leader should be the last in the "queue of mentors" especially when you don't know the domain. Your duty is to find a mentor, or make it possible that your new colleague have time for self learning.

A couple of tips:

- Find a senior tester in your organisation and ask him to provide a 2-4 hour long tutorial for your colleague
- Make it possible that your colleague have time to read testing related blogs like the [google testing blog](http://googletesting.blogspot.hu/) and videos
- Buy him (or her) the [agile testing book](http://lisacrispin.com/agile-testing-book-is-now-out/)
- set up a safe to fail environment (this has nothing to do with testing, but important)
- send him (or her) to a testing conference like the [agile testing days](http://www.agiletestingdays.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Mentoring is not what you are looking for.  Nor should your focus--at least primarily--be to nurture and grow this new testing individual.  Your focus should be enabling a high performing testing capability and you need four high performing enablers to do this: people, process & method, tools, and institutional knowledge.  If any of these enablers are under performing, so too is your capability.

On the people side of this equation, you need the human resources that have the knowledge, skills, and abilities (KSA) to perform the task.  This tester may have degrees of each of these, but as a person new to the workforce he is largely untested and is less likely to have the degree to run testing by himself.

Instead of mentoring, I would focus on finding the individual who can close the gaps on the KSAs required to perform the task, whether you have a part-time resource who would assist the NOOB or replace him completely.  Pros and cons to everything so you need to analyze that a bit.

If your counter argument would be you cannot afford to bring on someone else, my counter counter would be: pay now or pay more later; either way, you are going to pay.